# add active class in menu li using jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css

As of now i'm using code like this

```
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $("#menu li").click(function(){ 
      if ($("#menu li").hasClass('active')) {
        $("#menu li").removeClass('active'); 
      }
    $(this).addClass('active');
 });
});
</script>
```

Its working only for tabbed navigation.

But my site uses different pages. I mean each href points to different pages.

Can someone tell me how to add active class to `li` either using jquery or css.?

Thanks

Comment: If your posting back between each tab click, it would be better to append that class on the server side when the menu renders.

Answer (score 5):

Try following.

```
$('li').each(function(){
    if(window.location.href.indexOf($(this).find('a:first').attr('href'))>-1)
    {
    $(this).addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
    }
});
```

Comment: thanks bro. you make my day.this lines saved my lots of time.

Answer (score 1):

You can add an active class to a page and run it in a similar way. When the page loads (*document.ready()*), tell it to attach the active class to the current page menu list item.

```
$(/*Your current page menu item*/).addClass('active');
```